# R: Error with gsub - removing elements in string

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, radix, computation

I have a list of file names.
One of the file names is:

```
ABC_Earth_FullData_3-4-06.csv
```

I want a variable that is a substring of the filename with the date in date format only:

```
3-4-06
```

I am having trouble using gsub().
So far I've used:

```
file_date <- gsub(file_name = file_date, pattern = "ABC_Earth_FullData_", replacement = "", fixed = T)
```

And keep getting this error:

```
Error in gsub(file_name = file_date, pattern = "ABC_Earth_FullData_", :unused argument (file_name = file_date)
```

Comment: *"I am having trouble"*, okay. How? What have you tried, and what errors/warnings or incorrect output does it give?

Comment: `gsub(".*_([-0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", "ABC_Earth_FullData_3-4-06.csv")`

Comment: If you're having a problem with `gsub`, why did you add tags [tag:dplyr], [tag:lubridate], and [tag:computation]?

Comment: @r2evans thanks for your suggestion, I added more info to my quesiton.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, why are you adding the `file_name=` argument name? `gsub` has nothing to do with files, its arguments are `pattern=`, `replacement=`, `x=`, `ignore.case=`, `perl=`, `fixed=`, and `useBytes=`. ([`?gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) and `names(formals(gsub))` give this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_name is not a valid gsub argument, have a look at help

```
   ?gsub
```

try :

```
file_date <- gsub(x=file_name,pattern = "ABC_Earth_FullData_", replacement = "",fixed = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(str1, '.*_|\\..*')
#[1] "3-4-06"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'ABC_Earth_FullData_3-4-06.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` and backreference:

```
sub(".*_(.*)\\.csv", "\\1", str1)
[1] "3-4-06"
```